Printing a PDF File Silently in a WinRT App using C++ without Displaying any Window
I am developing a WinRT application for Windows using C++. I have the path to a PDF file (stored on disk) and the name of the printer. My goal is to print this PDF file programmatically (silently) without displaying any window or printer dialog. How can I achieve this in my WinRT app?
I need guidance on the necessary steps, APIs, and techniques to accomplish this task. Any insights, code snippets, or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
// #include <winrt/Windows.Data.Pdf.h>
// using namespace Windows::Data::Pdf;

winrt::hstring path = L"D:\\test.pdf";

StorageFile storagePdfFile = StorageFile::GetFileFromPathAsync (path).get ();

PdfDocument pdfDocument    = PdfDocument::LoadFromFileAsync (storagePdfFile, L"").get ();

int count      = pdfDocument.PageCount ();
int nPageIndex = 0;

while (nPageIndex < count) {

        PdfPage pdfPage = pdfDocument.GetPage (nPageIndex++);

    // This pdfPage need to be passed to the printer somehow, Not able to find a way
}


https://github.com/marb2000/PrintSample

I have my custom printer selection dialog box from which I get the name of the printer selected by the user. Now using that printer I want to print a PDF file that is stored on the disk at a particular path.

Unfortunately, it is not able to print silently using WinRT APIs. Printing without confirmation requires work at the security / isolation level, not just the UI level.
More information here: https://github.com/microsoft/WindowsAppSDK/issues/124
